# How to get records in JSON format from the model in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am accessing model data using the `.find` method but how to get records in JSON format from the model? I am getting output from `.find()` as: (Console log view)

> Class {type: function, store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: true, toString: function…}
>   ember1375269653627: "ember313" __ember1375269653627_meta: Meta _super: undefined get content: function () { isLoaded: true isUpdating: false set content: function (value) { store: Class toString: function () { return ret; } type: Grid.ModalModel __proto: Object

I am new user of this community, so unable to upload image.

Comment: When i tried to get output in json data format using model.toJSON()i got following error :
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {...........has no method 'toJSON'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ember Model, you do model.toJSON().  If you are trying to get values from the model you should use the getter model.get('name').

Comment: When i tried to get output in json data format using model.toJSON()i got following error :
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {...........has no method 'toJSON'

Answer (score 0):

In javascript to create a JSON out of javascript object you may want to use:

```
JSON.stringify({name: "John"}); // => "{"name":"John"}"
```

It works pretty good for plain `Ember.Object`s. But you may not want to stringify all properties of given object. In such case you should use `getProperties` method of `EmberObject`. For example:

```
var john = Ember.Object.create({firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", title: "CEO"});
JSON.stringify(john); // => "{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe", "title": "CEO"}"

var namesOnly = john.getProperties("firstName","lastName");
JSON.stringify(namesOnly); // => "{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}"
```